# How to open specific view from Push notification of IOS app when app is killed or not running?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, firebase

I am struggling to find the solution for opening a specific view of my IOS app when i get notification, i want to open a screen when user taps on received notification.

I am able to get the notification and when app is in background and i tap on notification it redirects me to specific view, it does also work when app is in active state but it just opens app when i tap on it and app is in killed state..

below is my appdelegate code

```
if application.applicationState == .inactive{

            print ("app is NOT active from not sec.")

            let articleId = userInfo["notification_id"] as? String

            UserDefaults.standard.set(articleId, forKey:"articleId");

            let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "notificationsPageSB") as UIViewController
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

            let isPromoFCM = 1 as? Int

            UserDefaults.standard.set(isPromoFCM, forKey:"isPromoFCM1");

        }
        else if application.applicationState == .active {

            let articleId = userInfo["notification_id"] as? String

            UserDefaults.standard.set(articleId, forKey:"articleId");

            print ("app is active from not sec.")
            let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "notificationsPageSB") as UIViewController
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


            /*     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
             let viewController: wow_Request_completed_vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "wow_Request_completed_vc") as! wow_Request_completed_vc;

             // Then push that view controller onto the navigation stack
             let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController;
             rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);


             self.window?.rootViewController!.performSegue(withIdentifier: "link_to_wow_completed_vc", sender: nil)
             */



                //let isOpenedThroughFCM = "yes"

            //UserDefaults.standard.set(isOpenedThroughFCM, forKey:"isOpenedThroughFCM");

            isComingFromFCM3 = 1;


        } else {

            // let isOpenedThroughFCM = "yes"

  //              UserDefaults.standard.set(isOpenedThroughFCM, forKey:"isOpenedThroughFCM");
            isComingFromFCM3 = 1;
            print ("app is NOT active from not sec.")

            let articleId = userInfo["notification_id"] as? String

            UserDefaults.standard.set(articleId, forKey:"articleId");

            let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "notificationsPageSB") as UIViewController
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }
```

Comment: with your provided code I can't figure out from where are you checking the app state, I think you'll never reach your aim using this approach as the app will change the state before running the code... just supposing. In your AppDelegate, are you checking the `launchOptions` ?

Comment: ya i have launchOptions code placed above didReceiveRemoteNotification method.. here i have pasted only didReceiveRemoteNotification few conditions

Comment: your code did worked and when i get notification and app is not running and i tap on it, its taking me to specific screen too, but its taking me to one screen for all the notifications

Comment: i have found the solution in didReceiveRemoteNotification completionHandler

Comment: @Swan any chance you can post your solution or explanation I'm also struggling with exact scenario? Thanks

Comment: @Swan can you post the answer please?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this, and the only one I know that works, is to check the `launchOption` keys in your delegate method.

```
    if (launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]) != nil {
        // check the userInfo and take the needed action
    }
```

Comment: ya this works, but i get many different notifications and i want to open specific view based on the notification i receive means every notification contains different purpose and i want user to navigate to specific view after click...if i want to get message payload information in this IF condition how to do that ?

Comment: Your need is the normal need for opening from push. The launch options is an object array that contains user info. I’m outside office now, but you can use an ‘if let’ instead of just an ‘if’ and load its content into a variable

Answer (score 0):

I can contribute to @GIJOW 's answer. Yes, that is doing the trick perfectly as I also looked for the same situation with remote notification methods. But in this case we need to handle them with `application:didFinisLaunchingWithOptions` for positive results. This worked for me. Hope this helps to some one else too.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    //This is what you are looking for
    if(launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]) != nil {
        if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? UNNotification {
            print("launching with Notification = ", notification)
            
            if ((notification.request.identifier).lowercased()).contains("checkingIndentifierSubstringHere") || ((notification.request.identifier).lowercased()).contains("IhaveMoreAdditionalSubstringCheckHere") {
                // Do your thing with validated notification Identifier
            }
        }
      }
    
     
    return true
}
```

So basically you can access `UNNotification` properties like I have access here for an example `notification.request.identifier`, when you use `launchOptions` unwrapped.

So, we could resolve calling actions here for the Notifications after user clicked on them when App is in killed (not running) state.

Comment: The first `if` statement is redundant with the `if let`. Just use the `if let` line and remove the first `if`.

Answer (score -2):

As my idea, let try to check `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber` value in

> - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

you can determine navigate somewhere or something here

UPDATE: my answer is Objective-C, but you can apply to Swift :p