# Xamarin.ios firebase push notification click issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app which implemented firebase push notifications.Currently I am playing with the ios portion. I can receive the notifications when App is in foreground, background and killed. The problem is handling the notification click.I am trying to call `MessagingCenter` from `DidReceiveNotificationResponse`
method in order to open a contentpage(My Notification details page in forms).I have two doubts

1. I am only handling the notification click from `DidReceiveNotificationResponse`
   method. I can able to handle the notification from this method. Currently I am testing on Iphone with `ios 12.4.6`. Is there any additional things to do for handling notifications on lower os versions? Or it is enough for all os versions?
2. How to handle the notification click when APP is in closed or killed state?Currently the app will navigate to my specific page on all scenarios, but in killed state the app itself will close the message details page after loading and navigate to home screen automatically.How to solve this?

**My DidReceiveNotificationResponse**

```
[Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action
    completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler();
        NSDictionary userInfo = response.Notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;
        var a = userInfo[new NSString("user_notification_id")] as NSString;
        try
        {            
            var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(userInfo[new NSString("user_notification_id")] as NSString);

            if (myData != null)
            {
                Settings.NotificationID = myData.ToString();
                Settings.NCNotificationStatus = null;
            }              
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        // Managing notification click here
        MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(new Object(), "iosNcnotificationTapped");
    }
```

**My App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public string Isnotification;
        public App(bool hasNotification = false)
        {       
            InitializeComponent();
            if (hasNotification)
            {
                var navPage = new NavigationPage(new LandingPage());
                Application.Current.MainPage = navPage;
                navPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ChatPage("26"));        
            }
            else
            {                         
                var splashPage = new CustomRender.TransitionNavigationPage(new SplashPage());
                MainPage = splashPage;            
            }   
                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "iosNcnotificationTapped", async (sender) => {                  
                        var navPage = new NavigationPage(new LandingPage());
                        Application.Current.MainPage = navPage;
                        await navPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ChatPage("26"));

                });
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        { 

        }
        protected override void OnSleep()
        {  

        }
        protected override void OnResume()
        {   

        }

    }
```

The `hasNotification` part is for android portion. For ios it will be always false.How to solve these issues?

Comment: 1. If it work in iOS 12, I think it will also work for lower versions. 2 Have a try with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50222792/10539446). It's a swift version and I can translate it to C# if you need.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Thanks for the reply. I think my probelm is with APP.xaml.cs portion. When we click notification,My thought is loadapplication part also invoking. The problem is only in app is killed state

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Can you help me to convert the solution suggested by you to the forms way?

Comment: I added an answer as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# version for the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222435/how-to-open-specific-view-from-push-notification-of-ios-app-when-app-is-killed-o/50222792#50222792)

In your iOS project:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{

    //if (launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]) != nil {
    //    // check the userInfo and take the needed action
    //}

    if (options != null)
    {
        NSObject result;
        if (options.TryGetValue(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey, out result))
        {
            //Get remoteNotification
        }
    }

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jack.Let me check it

Comment: You can follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiapplicationdelegate.finishedlaunching?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) for more information.

Comment: Still I am stuck at this because my messeging center in DidReceiveNotificationResponse will hit even if it is in killed state. So  how should I use this answer in this scenerio?

Comment: Since DidReceiveNotificationResponse hit in killed state, can you achieve what you want in that method? If not, use that solution in the answer.

Comment: Bro. Sorry for late reply. The  will hot even if the app is in killed state. and the messeging center portion will also hit. My desired page will also open. But after loading the desired page it suddently navigate to starting page in killed state. It it the problem

Comment: I don't know what happened when it suddently navigate to starting page in killed state. Did you try the solution in the answer to see if it works?

Comment: @Anand Does your problem resolved? You can share your solution here.

Comment: Bro. It solved my issue. I forgot to accept it. Sorry